# How to buffer events in reactive-banana

Tags: haskell, reactive-programming, frp, reactive-banana

I'm new in FRP, but want to try to apply FRP principles on practice. In many resources on the Internet related to FPR on Haskell authors refer to reactive-banana. So I thought to take a look at that as well, but it's not mandatory at all if there is better option to solve the problem.

Problem is:

I would like to build an application in Haskell which accepts users input events, should group them by user id and wait some time for each of them before firing request to web service.

So input generated by one user will be something like:

```
h
ha
has
...
haskel
haskell
```

and after some delay, let say 300ms without input events from user it should fire request with latest value, i.e. `haskell` in this example.

This problem can be solved relatively easy in C# with Rx extensions using `Buffer` as described **[here](http://www.introtorx.com/content/v1.0.10621.0/13_TimeShiftedSequences.html)**.

Is there something similar for Haskell?

Comment: It's certainly possible but you'll have to write it yourself

Comment: I have seen some advises to take a look at  [Wave.hs](https://github.com/HeinrichApfelmus/reactive-banana/blob/master/reactive-banana-wx/src/Wave.hs)
if no other option I guess it's way to go...

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888826/reactive-banana-throttling-events

Comment: Thanks, I have found it already. It looks pretty close to what I want, but looks quite big